# displaying the custom block only in full view mode in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

Iam New to drupal.I have created a custom block in drupal7.Now In this Block I want to display the data of custom content type(i.e for example Advertisements).This Advertisements have a faciltity to display the ads in homepage,teaser,full view mode page.

Now the problem is **I want to get programatically the view mode of block similar to node view so that I can get the advertisements related to that view(i.e advertisements with teaser view)** etc..

This is how I have implemented but it failed to show the view mode

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function Advertisement_block_view($delta = '',$view_mode) {

    echo $view_mode;   
    $block['subject'] = t('Advertisements');
    $block['content'] = Advertisement_block_content();
    return $block;
}
```

Please help with this..

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

By default Blocks do not support view modes. Not the way nodes do at least as far as I know of. Take a look at the **Drupal API** on the [hook_block_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) you used. It doesn't mention a `$view_mode` argument. You should actually be getting a warning if used.

Getting *Advertisements* (nodes) of a certain view mode sounds somewhat weird imo since you don't assign view modes onto nodes but onto a content type which means that all *Advertisement* nodes would be able to be viewed in a certain view mode once it is assigned to its content type.

If you want to get all view modes configured on a content type you can use: `field_view_mode_settings($entity_type, $bundle)` in which you pass `$entity_type = 'node'` & `$bundle = 'Your_advertisement_content_type_machine_name'`